# Do something if the condition true in hashmap filter collectors java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have the Map, In that keys are string and values are Employee object. It looks like Map, I'm new to Java 8 and in learning stage

```
Map<String, Employee> cond_Map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Employee>();

if(Obj.getEmp == null){
    cond_Map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if(key == "one"){
            Obj.setEmp(value);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to use filter to make this in single line and simple,

```
cond_Map.entrySet().stream().filter(key -> Python3Parser.If_stmtContext.class.isInstance(key.getKey())).collect(???);
```

but it won't works..! Does anybody have an idea?      Thank you.

Comment: Don´t say it won't work. Please say what is the error or incorrect behavior you get.

Comment: Surely `.collect(???)` doesn’t work. That’s not even valid Java syntax. And `Python3Parser.If_stmtContext.class.isInstance(key.getKey())` doesn’t even remotely match the condition `key == "one"` of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing `key == "one"` instead of `key.equals("one")`

another approach with filter.

```
    if (Obj.getEmp == null)
    {
        cond_Map.entrySet().stream()
           .filter(entry -> "one".equals(entry.getKey())).forEach(entry -> {
            Obj.setEmp(entry.getValue());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop over the map to find the entry with a matching key.  Finding the entry by key is the map's job:

```
if(Obj.getEmp == null && cond_Map.containsKey("one")){
    Obj.setEmp(cond_Map.get("one"));
}
```